# how to update SQL Server 2008 to 10.50?

Tags: sql-server, update, sql-server-2008-r2

I have windows server 2008 r2 running SQL Server 2008 version 10.0.1600.22 Enterprise Edition (64-bit), and i want to update it to 10.50. 
i tried to install [MSSQL Server SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26727)   and i got the following message "the are no sql server instances or shared features that can be updated on this computer"

Comment: Are you asking a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for MS SQL server 2008 R2. That is a separately licensed product that would require more of an upgrade than an update. For a reference of build numbers, google `Microsoft SQL Server build numbers`.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321185/how-to-determine-the-version,-edition-and-update-level-of-sql-server-and-its-components

Comment: thanks, i'll go with the express edition to test it out ,then i'll get the enterprise licence

Answer (score 1):

You downloaded the wrong thing.  What you tried to install was **service pack** 1 for SQL Server 2008 R2.  Upgrading from 2008 to 2008 R2 isn't a service pack.  It's a completely different version - like going from 2005 to 2008.